# Book (0.25kg) at rest on table.Force that Earth exerts on book is equal in magnitude to force that book exerts on Earth as this is Newton 3rd law pair

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Book (0.25kg) at rest on table.Force that Earth exerts on book is equal in magnitude to force that book exerts on Earth as this is Newton 3rd law pair. Please tell me if this statement made is correct and why.

Comment: Read; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force

Comment: @Drjh Why do you say it's not correct? (Question is a duplicate.) OP didn't ask about net force on book.

Comment: OP specifically asked _this is Newton 3rd law pair. Please tell me if this statement made is correct_ The answer is that "this statement is not correct". Hence why I said, it is not correct. Do you think otherwise?